# javascript- How to check if an object as a specific property

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I have this code, used to get a number of hours from an object and multiply them by a variable.

Here is the object 'work'

```
var work = [
    {'day': 27, 'hours': 7.30},
    {'day': 29, 'hours': 7.30},
    {'day': 31, 'hours': 10},
    {'day': 1, 'hours': 8.30},
    {'day': 2, 'hours': 7},
    {'day': 3, 'hours': 7},
    {'day': 5, 'hours': 7.30},
    {'day': 6, 'hours': 7},
    {'day': 7, 'hours': 7.30},
    {'day': 8, 'hours': 8},
    {'day': 9, 'hours': 9.30}
]

var payPerHour = 7;
```

and here my function to calculate the pay

```
function calculatePay()
{
    var result = 0, fResult = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < work.length; i++) {
        Object.keys(work).forEach(function (val) {
            if (work[i].hasOwnProperty('hours'))
              result = work[i][val] * payPerHour;

            fResult += result;
        });
    }

    return fResult;
}
```

I have used "hasOwnProperty" to check if the property "hours" exists in work. The result of the function is NaN. Why?

Comment: `Object.keys(work)` : what do you expect here ?

Comment: with he for loop i iterate over the array and then with  Object.keys(work) i go over the object that is in the array.

Comment: @DavidDume -- You dont need to iterate the object tho.

Comment: yeah, i thought it would make sense doing so. thanks for the help

Comment: All those `.30`'s make me wonder if your data is off a bit.  Should those be `.5` for half-hours? or `:30` for 30 minutes, with some further translation still to do before calculation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're already iterating your array via the `for` loop - then you do

```
Object.keys(work).forEach(function(val) {
```

This doesn't make any sense. `work` is an array - not an object. Basically if you remove that line it'll work:

```
for(var i = 0; i < work.length; i++) {
  //Object.keys(work).forEach(function(val) {
    if(work[i].hasOwnProperty('hours'))
      result = work[i]["hours"] * payPerHour; //use the right property here

    fResult += result;
  //});
}
```

A simpler way may be to use `Array.reduce`

```
var totalHourPay = work.reduce(function(total, workDay) {
    if (workDay.hasOwnProperty("hours")) {
         total += workDay.hours * payPerHour;
    }

    return total;
}, 0);
```

Comment: Or simply `work.reduce((total, workDay) => total + (workDay.hours || 0) * payPerHour, 0)`.

Comment: @ScottSauyet -- Ya - if the ES6 syntax is available :D

Comment: Sure, the ES6 is a nice change, but also removing the `hasOwnProperty` check in favor of `|| 0` makes it more succinct, and to my eyes more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript for..in loops like below:

```js
function calculatePay() {
    var result = 0, fResult = 0;
    for(var index in work) {
        if(work[index].hasOwnProperty('hours'))
   result = work[index]['hours'] * payPerHour;
   fResult += result;
    }
     return fResult;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why these complicated expressions? Try this ES6 solution:

```js
var work = [{'day':27,'hours':7.30},{'day':29,'hours':7.30},{'day':31,'hours':10},
           {'day':1,'hours':8.30},{'day':2,'hours':7},{'day':3,'hours':7},
           {'day':5,'hours':7.30},{'day':6,'hours':7},{'day':7,'hours':7.30},
           {'day':8,'hours':8},{'day': 9, 'hours': 9.30}],
           calculatePay=(b)=>work.reduce((c,d)=>c+d.hours*b,0)

// Test
console.log( calculatePay(7) ) // Returns 600.6 and 7 is your rate per hour

// Or redefine function calculatePay this way if you need ES5 compatibility
// function calculatePay(a) {
//   return work.reduce(function(b,c) {
//     return b + c.hours * a
//   }, 0)
// }

// And if you really needs use hasOwnProperty, define it this way
// function calculatePay(a) {
//   return work.reduce(function(b,c) {
//     return b + (c.hasOwnProperty('hours') && c.hours || 0) * a
//   }, 0)
// }

// But you dont need hasOwnProperty. You are processing simple array,
// not object. And this array is full of ordinary object literals. None of
// them does not inherits anything from another object, unless you override
// Object itself.
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you wanted:

```
var work = [{'day': 27, 'hours': 7.30},
      {'day': 29, 'hours': 7.30},
      {'day': 31, 'hours': 10},
      {'day': 1, 'hours': 8.30},
      {'day': 2, 'hours': 7},
      {'day': 3, 'hours': 7},
      {'day': 5, 'hours': 7.30},
      {'day': 6, 'hours': 7},
      {'day': 7, 'hours': 7.30},
      {'day': 8, 'hours': 8},
      {'day': 9, 'hours': 9.30}
      ];

var payPerHour = 7;

var result = 0, fResult = 0;

function calculatePay(){

for(var i = 0; i < work.length; i++) {
   Object.keys(work).forEach(function() {

   result = work[i].hours * payPerHour;
   fResult += result;
 });

}

console.log("Final total: " +fResult);
}

calculatePay();
```